# Proof of: $m = n = 0 \iff m + n =0$ $n,m \in N$

Tags: proof-verification, summation

I need to prove only one way,

I know that $m + n =0$ with $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$  $\implies m = n = 0$

only using sum axioms
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n+0=n$

Comment: why the downvote? I need help with this, if you need more info, please ask me to clarify it. 
"@german-faller is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering. "

Comment: I don't understand which way do you need guidance with. Care to clarify?

Comment: Also, your post could use some formatting, I'm not even talking about the TeX part, just basic punctuation would be nice. Right now this comes across as low-effort, which may explain why someone has given you a downvote. In any case, I can help you out as soon as you can clarify which implication you are having trouble with.

Comment: I am a bit confused about a fact that $0\notin\mathbb{N}$ so how can we say $m=n=0 $?

Comment: I need this for Computer science, may be we abuse the definition but dosen't matters, think in $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\} \implies m,n\geq0.$
Suppose $m\neq0$, then $m\geq1$ so $m+n\geq1$ and $0\geq1$, contradiction.